# xslt - select node with specific subnode

Tags: xslt, xpath

I have an xml:

```
<mynodes>
   <mynode>
     <element1>a</element1>
     <element2>b</element2>
   </mynode>
   <mynode>
     <element1>c</element1>
     <element2>d</element2>
   </mynode>
</mynodes>
<translation>
  <col>element2</col>
  <cont>d</cont>
</translation>
```

I need an xpath, which gives me the the element1 content of the same subnode.

I have tried different xpaths, always with error.

My idea was to:

```
<xsl:variable name="col" select="/translation/col" />
<xsl:variable name="cont" select="/translation/cont" />
<xsl:value-of select="/mynodes/mynode[./name()=$col and ./text()=$cont]/element1" />
```

I have tried many things. Any idea?
I did not want to loop the structure, because the structure is quite big and there are several queries to do.

Comment: Can you elaborate a little about "the element1 content of the same subnode"? Do you want to check /translation/col value and extract text from /mynodes/mynode child node with the same name?

Answer (score 0):

Use `<xsl:value-of select="/mynodes/mynode[*[name()=$col and . = $cont]]/element1"/>`

Answer (score 0):

XSLT has a built-in **[key](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116/#key)** mechanism for resolving cross-references - and it would be best to use it, esp. if you have "several queries to do".

Here you could define the key as:

```
<xsl:key name="k1" match="*" use="concat(name(), '|', .) " />
```

and then call it from the context of `translation` as::

```
<xsl:value-of select="key('k1', concat($col, '|', $cont))/../element1"/>
```